# How push only the files from commit to git remote in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

In my project, when I choose "commit changes", I get a pop-up window where I can unselect some files. After doing this and clicking "commit and push", on the push window it still shows the files I unselected and there's no way to unselect them.

After a push, it shows those files' changes on the remote server.

How do I keep certain file changes from being pushed to the remote?

I don't want to remove them from git source control, just from pushing my changes of them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't push files to your remote, you push commits (changesets). That's why Intellij wouldn't allow you to deselect anything when you are pushing.

Pushing basically sends a commit delta (commits you have and the remote doesn't) to the remote.

Comment: Yes, but if you notice in my post, I did *not* commit those files. During the commit window, I uncheck them. So they shouldn't be committed. So why are their changes getting pushed?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I missed that part. Can you include some screenshots of the process?